# Attaching an excel file to email from memory (without saving it to the system)

Tags: python, pandas, attachment, mandrill

I generate an excel file from a few data frames using pandas:

```
def to_excel(x, y, z): 

    filename = 'x_y_z_' + date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
    x.to_excel(writer, 'x')
    y.to_excel(writer, 'y')
    z.to_excel(writer, 'z')
    writer.close()

    return writer
```

This is the function that we use to create the message for Mandrill

```
def create_message(variables, from_name, from_email, to_addrs, bcc_addrs, subject, tags=None, images=None, attachments=None):
    """ Create template_content and message to use with mandrill. 
    :param variables: dict or list of variables
    :param str from_email:
    :param str to_addrs: 
    :param str subject:
    :param list tags:
    """
    template_content = []

    if type(variables) == dict:
        global_merge_vars = [{'name': key, 'content': value} for key, value in variables.iteritems()]
    elif type(variables) == list:
        global_merge_vars = variables
    else:
        print 'Variables type is not list or dictionary. Please update variables'
        sys.exit()

    message = {
        'from_email': from_email,
        'from_name': from_name,
        'to': [{'email': x, } for x in to_addrs] + [{'email': x, 'type': 'bcc'} for x in bcc_addrs], 
        'subject': subject,
        'preserve_recipients': True,
        'merge': True,
        'merge_language': "handlebars",
        'global_merge_vars': global_merge_vars,
        'tags': tags,
        'images':images,
        'attachments':attachments
    }

    return template_content, message
```

This is the error that occurs.
`TypeError: <pandas.io.excel._Openpyxl22Writer object at 0x10efe7210> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: we don't know how you are interfacing with Mandril. please provide a complete program that demonstrates the error

Comment: This problem happens because the other library is expecting something different than the writer object you are returning. What are your Mandril API expecting? The file name? An open file object?

Comment: @PauloScardine now i am thinking it expects a filename

Comment: should it be write.save()?  your 'x', 'y', 'z' are the sheets nameS?

Comment: So use `writer.save()` and return `os.path.abspath(filename)`.

Comment: If you want to save to a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058563/write-to-stringio-object-using-pandas-excelwriter