# Pandas to_excel to write a dataframe results in blank spreadsheet - how write to excel using xlwt?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel, xlwt

Writing a dataframe:

```
New_DF = 
            caviae  species  murliniae  freundii  braakii  freundii  cloacae  \
15368485     NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN   
15368486     NaN      NaN        NaN         1      NaN         1      NaN   
15368487     NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN   
15368488     NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN   
15368489     NaN        1        NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
```

etc
to a .xls spreadsheet, workbook 'Sheet1':

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import xlwt

New_DF = pd.DataFrame(SpeciesCount,labNo,Species)

xlwt_writer = pd.io.excel.get_writer('xlwt')

my_writer = xlwt_writer('C:\Users\Georgina\Documents\Test\1291707 STS Excel Extract.xls')

xl_out = StringIO.StringIO()
my_writer.path = xl_out
New_DF.to_excel(my_writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',startrow = 4)
my_writer.save()
```

This doesn't alter the .xls file or output an error message

Any help much appreciated

Comment: what is `xl_out` supposed to do? That's probably empty and resets the path of xlwt_writer to None or the empty string.

Comment: I got that from reading various other help pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058563/write-to-stringio-object-using-pandas-excelwriter    I have changed the xl_out to the path that the file is in & now it has an issue with the my_writer.save() line. It gives me the error: "in save
    f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Georgina\\Documents\\Software Development\\Bacti Comments Auto-sort' "

Comment: I have permissions for that directory according to windows exporer

Comment: how was this solved? I have the same problem in windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import xlwt

New_DF = pd.DataFrame(SpeciesCount,labNo,Species)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\Users\Georgina\Documents\Test\1291707 STS Excel Extract.xls', engine='xlwt')
New_DF.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow = 4)
writer.save()
```