# TypeError: invalid file: None when exporting dataframes with xlsxWriter

Tags: python, excel, flask, xlsxwriter

I've been using XLSXWriter on my Python/Flask app to export dataframes to Excel. Until today, I managed to export my dataframes on one worksheet; now I'm trying to export multiple dataframes on different worksheets inside one single file.

When I try locally (see first code attached), everything works perfectly. But when I write to an IOStream, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: invalid file: None
```

Here is the functional local code:

```
    path_user = expanduser("~").split("\\")[-1]

    xlsx_path = r"C:\Users\{}\Desktop\ExportAllGraphs2.xlsx".format(path_user)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

    count = 0

    for df in df_list:

        sheet_title = df["title"].split(' ', 1)[0]    
        sheet_name = "{}_{}".format(count, sheet_title)

        df_header.to_excel(writer,startrow = 0, merge_cells = False, sheet_name = sheet_name)
        df["df"].to_excel(writer,startrow = len(df_header) + 5, merge_cells = False, sheet_name = sheet_name)

        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
        format = workbook.add_format()
        format.set_bg_color('#eeeeee')
        worksheet.set_column(0,50,20)
        worksheet.write(len(df_header) + 4, 1, df["title"])

        count += 1

    writer.close()
    os.system('start excel.exe "{}"'.format(xlsx_path))
```

and here is the non-functioning live code:

```
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')

    count = 0

    for df in df_list:

        sheet_title = df["title"].split(' ', 1)[0]    
        sheet_name = "{}_{}".format(count, sheet_title)

        df_header.to_excel(writer,startrow = 0, merge_cells = False, sheet_name = sheet_name)
        df["df"].to_excel(writer,startrow = len(df_header) + 5, merge_cells = False, sheet_name = sheet_name)

        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
        format = workbook.add_format()
        format.set_bg_color('#eeeeee')
        worksheet.set_column(0,50,20)
        worksheet.write(len(df_header) + 4, 1, df["title"])

        count += 1

    writer.close()
    output.seek(0)

    return send_file(output, 
    attachment_filename="test_export_{}.xlsx".format(current_date), 
    as_attachment=True)
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058563/write-to-stringio-object-using-pandas-excelwriter

Comment: I don't believe so; the solution to the issue is to that question is something I use in my code already.