# How to decode an encoded excel file using python

Tags: java, python, pandas, encoding, base64

My java programmer converted an excel file to binary and sending the binary content to me.

He used `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` and `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder()` for encoding.

I need to convert that binary data to a data frame using python.

the data looks like,

`UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHl........`

I tried `bas64` decoder but not helped.

my code:

```
import base64
with open('encoded_data.txt','rb') as d:
    data=d.read()
print(data)
`UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHl........`
decrypted=base64.b64decode(data)
print(decrypt)
  'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00b\xee\x9dh^\x01\x00\x00\x90\x04\x00\x00\x13\x00\x08\x02[Content_Types].xml \xa2\x04\x02(\xa0\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Please help me to convert this binary data to a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Can you show your complete input data which needs to be decoded? and your sample code?

Comment: Just one sample data that you need to decode which in base64 from java and code where you tried decoding.

Comment: print one of the data as well. which you tried decoding.

Comment: The resulting string after base64 starts with PK which suggests it is a ZIP archive compression. Which is actually normal for a xlsx, which contains xml inside a ZIP.

Comment: I edited my question, pls tell me if the data is insufficient

Comment: data=d.read() print this data as well.

Comment: No idea about panda, but I am sure most data processing frameworks have an importer for excel.

Comment: You said your data looks like this: UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQBi7p1oXgEAAJAEAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHl, is this after your variable decrypt?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're almost there. Since the decrypted object is a bytes string, why not use `BytesIO`?

```
import io
import pandas as pd

toread = io.BytesIO()
toread.write(decrypted)  # pass your `decrypted` string as the argument here
toread.seek(0)  # reset the pointer

df = pd.read_excel(toread)  # now read to dataframe
```

Answering your question from your comment: How to convert a df to a binary encoded object?

Well, if you want to convert it back to an b64 encoded object with pandas converting it as an excel, then:

```
towrite = io.BytesIO()
df.to_excel(towrite)  # write to BytesIO buffer
towrite.seek(0)  # reset pointer
encoded = base64.b64encode(towrite.read())  # encoded object
```

To write the encoded object to a file (just to close the loop :P):

```
with open("file.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(encoded)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly. I have not used io module

Comment: @pyd Updated my answer to address your comment :)

Comment: `AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'write_cells'` getting this error on `df.to_excel(towrite)`

Comment: You are probably using a different excel writer engine than me. This post should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058563/write-to-stringio-object-using-pandas-excelwriter

Comment: Ok I'll try that one

Answer (score 2):

You can do with openpyxl module also
Here is the modified code

```
import base64
import io
import openpyxl

with open('encoded_data.txt','rb') as d:
    data=d.read()
print(data)
decrypted=base64.b64decode(data)
print(decrypted)

xls_filelike = io.BytesIO(decrypted)
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(xls_filelike)
sheet_obj = workbook.active
max_col = sheet_obj.max_column 
max_row = sheet_obj.max_row

# Will print all the row values
for i in range(1, max_row +1):
    for j in range(1, max_col + 1):         
        cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = j) 
        print cell_obj.value, 
        print ",", "Inorder to seperate the cells using comma for readability
    print ""
```

Comment: What is this? `xls_filelike = io.BytesIO(decoded_data)?` where is `decoded_data`?

Comment: May be its typo, use `decrypted` instead of  decoded_data.

Comment: Sorry for typo. Corrected now. Thanks @heaven2sai