# Unit test for reading an excel file witth pandas

Tags: excel, python-2.7, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test case for the below code :

```
    def read_data(self, data):

    """Read data from excel file.

    :param data:str, data in file
    :return:str, data after reading excel file
    """
    try:
        read_data = pd.read_excel(data)
        return read_data
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("Not able to read data. Error :- {}".format(e))
        raise e
```

I am reading an excel file in the above code, which gives me data like this:
[refer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg4kg.png).

So, How to store the above data after reading from excel sheet as dummy data so that I can assert it to my original data?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Necroposting this because I had the same need.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065603/4149512) can point you in the right direction:

> See also [Saving the Dataframe](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#saving-the-dataframe-output-to-a-string) output to a string in the XlsxWriter docs.

From the example you can build something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

output = io.BytesIO()

# Use the BytesIO object as the filehandle.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write the data frame to the BytesIO object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()

# Read the BytesIO object back to a data frame - here you should use your method
xlsx_data = pd.read_excel(output)

# Assert that the data frame is the same as the original
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(xlsx_data, df)
```

Basically you flip the problem around: you build a data frame with some data in it, save it in a temporary file-like object, pass that object to your method, and then assert that the data is the same as the one you created.

**NOTE:** It needs pandas 0.17+